# Why does my Perl script fail to connect to the database?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, perl-module

I have a Perl script which retrieves data from MySQL Database. this is the code:

```
sub startSession{
    my $self = shift;

    my $dsn = "dbi:".$self{platform}.":".$self{database}.":".$self{host}.":".$self{port};
    print "$dsn\n" ;
    $self{dbHandle} = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password);   
}
```

I have provided every information from an external file. I get the error message

`DBI connect('dbname:**.**.**.**:3306','',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'dbserver' (using password: NO) at  line 89`

`Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at at line 97`

I am very sure the root can connect from any host and the password is also correct.

Comment: One problem is that `$self{...}` has nothing to do with `my $self = shift`.  You'd need to use `$self->{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your immediate problem, is as @Sinan Ünür says, that you need to change `$self{platform}` to `$self->{platform}`, etc.

Your second immediate problem is that it appears you're getting `$user` and `$password` from nowhere (they are not passed to the function, so they are undefined unless they are global variables), which would explain the `using password: NO` part of the error. Maybe those should be `$self->{user}` and `$self->{password}`?

You should considering put this at the top of your module, at least during development, to automatically catch errors like these:

```
use warnings qw(all);
use strict;
```

But I'd also comment, that from a design perspective, you really ought to treat DSNs as opaque strings. Each database has its own DSN format. So if you ever want to target a different database, you'll need a different DSN format. Or, possibly, someday MySQL will use a different format (it already has two). Either way, it'll be much easier to change it one place, in a configuration file, than to track down each place you concatenate the various pieces together.

Comment: Like I have said in the problem statement, `user` and `password` are taken from an external file.

Comment: @user1304082: That's what you think anyway. It's quite evident that `$user` and `$password` aren't even declared in the scope you're using them, and that you need to provide more context if you want help solving your problem.

Comment: @user1304082 I have clarified my answer. You haven't passed $user and $password to the function (or, if you have, you're missing the `my $user = shift;`, `my $password = shift;` lines), so unless those are global variables, they're undefined. `use strict` will catch this.

Answer (score 3):

The key part of the warning that I see is "**using password: NO**". Check that the password is being set properly.

Comment: How do I do that ? and one more thing, I dont even have a host named `'dbserver'`

Comment: If you turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` for this, I'd bet that it would give you more information on how to fix this than SO users.

Comment: It gave me this warnings `Global symbol "$user" requires explicit package name at dbAdmin.pm line 27.`
`Global symbol "$password" requires explicit package name at dbAdmin.pm line 27`

Comment: Somewhere in your script, you need to have `my $username = 'my_db_user';` and `my $password = 'my_db_password';`.

Comment: I did that, the machine is a new clean installation, do you think i need to install any mysql drivers on it before i use this script ?

Comment: Are you not getting the "global symbol requires package name" anymore?  Did you make the corrections that @cjm suggested, using $self-> to get the values out of whatever $self is referring to?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `$self` is a hashref, not a plain hash, and you don't have [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) on. So, turn them on, and use `$self->{platform}` etc.

Comment: these are the warnings  I get `Global symbol "$user" requires explicit package name at dbAdmin.pm line 27.
Global symbol "$password" requires explicit package name at dbAdmin.pm line 27`

Comment: Quite right, but the OP's immediate problem is that the call to `DBI->connect` is failing.

Comment: Then clearly your variables $user and $password aren't getting set from the external file you mentioned.  How are you doing that?